# how to script source tag code of a payment form in codeigniter which is a javascript form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

**brief** : I am passing $data['tabdata'] variable to view V from controller C, which contains a script element http://example.com/1.js >

**issue**: that script is not executing in view, basically that 1.js script contains a js form, and show a submit button.code sharing below. some pointers will help.
https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/checkout-form
 **code**

```
 $data['tabData'] = '<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"></head><body>false section
<form action="/purchase" method="POST">
<!-- Note that the amount is in paise = 50 INR -->
<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="<YOUR_KEY_ID>"
    data-amount="5000"
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="Merchant Name"
    data-description="Purchase Description"
    data-image="https://your-awesome-site.com/your_logo.jpg"
    data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
    data-prefill.email="test@test.com"
    data-theme.color="#F37254"
></script>
<input type="hidden" value="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form></body></html>';
      $this->load->view('tabview',$data);
```

Comment: pass all values in $data to view and add all html code in view page and set the $data values like amount in script properties... do not pass all form in $data.

Comment: its not a form we are creating, its payment gateway script just sourcing with some data attributes, and this Js contains the form.pls refer above code, we are trying to show that pay button on an Ajax tab, by passing all script in $data['tabdata']

Comment: there are 2 methods auto & manual... using manual you can able to achieve.. i was already integrated with manual system. using this you do not have to create any button.. you just have to pass the id of your already created button.

Comment: we are using ajax for tabs, that's why above script passing as a variable to Tab data, the challenge is form script src="" is not executing/loading in view otherwise the submit button should display. (can you explain how you achieved it? in my case ajax seems culprit , same code working in other views)

Comment: finally resolved it with manual method of razorpay.Thanks Ash

Answer (score 0):

When using Razorpay payment js checkout script in combination of Ajax, remember below points

#### 1 ) Must maintain form in view only , not in result query(at least this was our case)

#### 2) Use Manual method and post payment,capture txn id and redirect/log as per your requirement.

hope this helps!